# Systems of DE (Eigenvectors)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

In a $2\times 2$ system of differential equations with initial conditions how are the unknowns in the general solution ($C_1$ and $C_2$) calculated given that there are an infinite number of eigenvectors possible?  Won't that fact, which i'm assuming is true, yield infinitely many solutions, all affecting how the solution trajectories look?

Thanks.

Comment: D.E. problems require initial conditions in order to find particular solutions.

Comment: I understand that but the general form of the solution for these types of equations have the eigenvector for each eigenvalue in them.  I'm asking since there are many possible eigenvectors does any constant multiple of them give a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general form solution should be (with real eigenvalues) $$\vec{x}(t)=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}\vec{\eta}_1+c_2e^{\lambda_2t}\vec{\eta}_2$$ where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues and $\vec{\eta}$ are the eigenvectors. The arbitrary constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ are there because, as you say, there are an infinite amount of eigenvectors that satisfy the system, which is why we need the initial conditions.

Comment: I thought I was getting wrong answers because my eigenvectors didn't match those in my textbook examples, but after simplifying solutions (multiplying through) I see that my solutions are correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the general solution you only need two linearly independent eigenvectors along with the eigenvalues. The general solution is $$y= C_1 e^{\lambda _1t}V_1 + C_2  e^{\lambda _2t}V_2$$ where the coefficients are found from the initial values.